# How to exclude Javascript from raw html in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am making a scraper which scrapes the site with HTML tags but the problem is the site which I am scraping has ads between content so XPath selectors are scraping the scripts too, Which I don't want.

```
response.xpath('//*[@class="entry-inner"]/p').extract()
```

So How to exclude javascript from HTML?

Comment: can you show the full html or the url?

Comment: Sure Sir, I want to get the all the text content from this url -  http://lyricssingh com/dekhte-dekhte-lyrics-atif-aslam/

Comment: The url is invalid

Comment: No there is a space before com just add a (.) in between

Comment: i don't think ad will create any problem, BTW i see the result and nothing contains ads element/text.
run this and check..

response.xpath('//*[@class="entry-inner"]/p/text()').extract()

Comment: Sir I need HTML tags such as p and br I can't use text() here, anyway out of this?

Comment: response.xpath('//*[@class="entry-inner"]/p[2]/text()').extract()

Comment: response.css('div.entry-inner > p:nth-of-type(4)').extract()

Comment: worked thank you so much you are a genius

Comment: Wait! but second is not fecting the entire content

Comment: change the nth-of-type

Comment: Oh No! SO I have to loop over all the nth element and pass if there is a script? and add them in the end?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181487/discussion-between-sohan-das-and-abhijeet-pal).